# HTML Tidy.dll for PyTidyLib

Tags: python, html, htmltidy

I am trying to find Tidy.dll or a windows installer to use PyTidyLib, but all the correct links http://tidy.sourceforge.net/#source seem to be dead. Any ideas where to find those?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may find the following links to be useful.

**INSTALLER:** http://www.paehl.com/open_source/?download=tidy.zip

**DLL:** http://www.paehl.com/open_source/?download=libtidy.7z

Answer (score 0):

You can get binaries on the official page:
[HTML Tidy Binary Releases](http://binaries.html-tidy.org)